# match groups of words and digits regex in any order

Tags: regex

suppose you have the following string:

"7 apples and 13 oranges"

```
/(\d+).*?(apples)/i
```

the above regex will match 7 apples but if you alternate the order and numbers to "45 oranges and 9 apples".it will match the first digit 45 rather than the digit corresponding to apples, which I want.

How can I write a regex to match and return match groups of digits + apples if I write the sentence in the following two orders:

1. "7 apples and 13 oranges"
2. "13 oranges 52 apples"

ie, I'd like to match 7 apples, with the match groups of 7 and apples AND 52 apples with the match groups 52 and apples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Where you got wrong in `/(\d+).*?(apples)/i` ?

`.*?` even though it is a lazy matching it matches from the digit to next `apple`

which means that for string

`"13 oranges 52 apples"`

It matches from `13` till the `apple` at the end of the string, since `.` matches *anything*

see the link for an illustration : http://regex101.com/r/uL5eX0/2

- How to correct?

since the symbol seperating your digit and apple is a space, you can use a `\s` character instead of `.` as

```
(\d+)\s(apples)
```

matches `7` and `52` as seen in http://regex101.com/r/uL5eX0/3

For safe side you can have

`(\d+)\s+(apples)`

any number of spaces between digit and apple

a word boundary `\b` can also be used for extra safety

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)(?=\s*(apples))
```

Try this.Use a postive lookahead.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/17

Comment: @nu11p01n73R sometimes :P

Comment: *with the match groups of 7 and apples* i think op wants apples as well but i dont know why

Comment: @JanDvorak i thought of the same solution. which was the only reason to upvote. The comment was just to appreciate the speed he had. Hope it is fine

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern
<strike>`(\d+)\s++(apples\b)`</strike>

by popular demand from the crowed.

```
(\d+)\s+(apples\b)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/87)

Comment: Why? Particularly, can you explain the second `+` in `\s++`? Why isn't there any in `\d++`?

Comment: OP didn't specify Java. OP didn't specify PCRE. OP didn't specify a regex engine. `++` is not the way to go.

Comment: my goodness, my answer covered more examples than all the rest, yet everyone is picking on the `++` ??!!!

Comment: @alphabravo more examples? All I can see is "use this: [code] [demo link]". Any external resource can go away eventually and an answer should be self-sufficient even if they break.

Comment: for the time being and until the external resource is gone away the answer is sufficient, maybe not self-sufficient but that is not the point, the point here is my answer covered a lot of scenarios also OP did not specify Jave or PCRE so until then my answer is valid, I do agree however `++` was not necessary here (act of hapit). Peace brother, smile

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `\D*?` instead of `.*?` where `.` would match the in-between digit but `\D` wouldn't.

```
(\d+)\D*?(apples)
```

`\D*?` Non-greedy match of any character but not of a digit zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eE2kR4/1)

What's wrong with your regex?

```
(\d+).*?(apples)
```

At first regex engine would try to match characters which satisfy the given pattern from left to right. So `\d+` would match the first number and `.*?(apples)` forces the engine to match all the characters upto the string `apple`. Use `\D*?` instead of `.*?` to force the engine to match any character but not of a digit zero or more digits.